# PowerShell Script finding File using extension and excluding a folder

Tags: powershell

I am using the below code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path N:\USERS -Filter DANTOM.DTM -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

I need it to either find the file "DANTOM.DTM" or the extension ".DTM". I need to exclude the folder N:\USERS\EDI because it is a 1.7TB folder that would never have this file in it. So in doing so would really speed up the process.

I would like the end result to either spit into a .txt file saying which folders inside of N:\USERS has the file or just have it display as a list in powershell.

Thank you,

Comment: So you just want `GCI C:\Users\* -Directory -Exclude 'EDI' | %{GCI $_ -Include DANTOM.DTM -Recurse -Force -EA 0}|Set-Content "$home\desktop\DTM Location.txt"`

Comment: I tried your code, It just sits and runs forever. No text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the files of interest do not reside directly in `N:\USERS` (only in subdirs.), try the following (PSv3+ syntax); send to a file by appending `> dirs.txt`, for instance.

```
Get-ChildItem N:\USERS -Directory | ? Name -ne 'EDI' | 
  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.DTM | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.DirectoryName }
```

Note: While it is tempting to try a simpler approach with `-Exclude EDI`, it unfortunately doesn't seem to be effective in excluding the entire *subtree* of the `EDI` subfolder.

Comment: @KevinMissildine: append, e.g., `> dirs.txt` to get a UTF16-LE-encoded text file, or, if you want to control the output encoding, append something like `| Out-File -Encoding utf8 dirs.txt` or `| Set-Content -Encoding utf8 dirs.txt` (with string output, `>` and `Out-File` on the one hand, and `Set-Content` on the other behave the same, apart from the default encoding used.)

Comment: @KevinMissildine: my pleasure; glad to hear it helped.